# How to draw a canvas element using Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am using the Phaser 3 JavaScript graphics library: https://phaser.io/phaser3

I have a canvas element that I have previously created, outside of the library. I now want to draw this canvas element on the screen using Phaser 3. As a toy example, consider the following code:

```
const game = new Phaser.Game({
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 1000,
    height: 1000,
    scene: {
        create,
    },
});

function create() {
    // Create a circle
    // From: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_arc.asp
    const circle = document.createElement('canvas');
    const ctx = circle.getContext('2d');
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();

    // Draw the circle using Phaser 3
    const circleTexture = this.textures.createCanvas('circle');
    circleTexture.setDataSource(circle);
    circleTexture.refresh();
    const circleImage = this.add.image(150, 200, 'circle');
}
```

When run, this code does not draw anything to the screen. What is the correct way to accomplish this task?

Comment: The second part of `create` function code won't work since `textures` and `add` do not exist in the scope. You'd bind `create` with the appropriate context in the `Phaser.Game` instance.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow what you are saying. Anyway, the (new) code snippet that I just posted below works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is this:

```
this.textures.addCanvas('circle', circle);
```

So, the full working code is as follows:

```
const game = new Phaser.Game({
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 1000,
    height: 1000,
    scene: {
        create,
    },
});

function create() {
    // Create a circle
    // From: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_arc.asp
    const circle = document.createElement('canvas');
    const ctx = circle.getContext('2d');
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();

    // Draw the circle using Phaser 3
    this.textures.addCanvas('circle', circle);
    const circleImage = this.add.image(150, 200, 'circle');
}
```